# NASA World Wind Documentation for C#

Tags: c#, documentation, worldwind

I have just started working on NASA world Wind Application in C#. But I am not be able to find documentation or tutorials for C# WW application. Please tell me if there is any help or documentation for NASA C# World Wind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem might be that NASA no longer has funding to support the C# version as of last year as indicated by a post from their forum. This might be why you're hard pressed to find information.

http://forum.worldwindcentral.com/showthread.php?t=25201

Answer (score 1):

I found this, it doesn't look like full documentation, but it's something, http://issues.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/confluence/display/WWNET/Home;jsessionid=843B4699FE2945F2A9A363F9D87A1294.

I noticed that some of the links just go to blank pages, but not all of them.